# Receive fragmented messages with selectors

Tags: python, sockets

Due to the fact that TCP packets can become fragmented during transport, you have to call recv() until it returns 0. This is reflected in [the python socket documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example).

```py
# Echo server program
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data: break
            conn.sendall(data)
```

Python selectors seem to be pretty cool, there is one aspect that puzzles me though.
The [example in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html#examples) suggests to call recv() just a single time.

```py
import selectors
import socket

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()

def accept(sock, mask):
    conn, addr = sock.accept()  # Should be ready
    print('accepted', conn, 'from', addr)
    conn.setblocking(False)
    sel.register(conn, selectors.EVENT_READ, read)

def read(conn, mask):
    data = conn.recv(1000)  # Should be ready
    if data:
        print('echoing', repr(data), 'to', conn)
        conn.send(data)  # Hope it won't block
    else:
        print('closing', conn)
        sel.unregister(conn)
        conn.close()

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('localhost', 1234))
sock.listen(100)
sock.setblocking(False)
sel.register(sock, selectors.EVENT_READ, accept)

while True:
    events = sel.select()
    for key, mask in events:
        callback = key.data
        callback(key.fileobj, mask)
```

How can I make sure I read until I have received everything the other side has sent? Adding a loop like in the straight socket example doesn't work, as that results in a **BlockingIOError**.

```py
import selectors
import socket

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()


def accept(sock, mask):
    conn, addr = sock.accept()  # Should be ready
    print('accepted', conn, 'from', addr)
    conn.setblocking(False)
    sel.register(conn, selectors.EVENT_READ, read)


def read(conn, mask):
    d = bytearray()
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1000)  # Should be ready
        if data:
            d.extend(data)
        else:
            print('closing', conn)
            sel.unregister(conn)
            conn.close()
            break

    print('echoing', repr(data), 'to', conn)
    conn.send(data)  # Hope it won't block


sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('localhost', 1234))
sock.listen(100)
sock.setblocking(False)
sel.register(sock, selectors.EVENT_READ, accept)

while True:
    events = sel.select()
    for key, mask in events:
        callback = key.data
        callback(key.fileobj, mask)
```

Of course I can leave the read() function and trust that I'll get another EVENT_READ and then append what i get to a buffer i keep somewhere. But how do I then differentiate between transmissions from the client? i.e. how do i detect when a single send() from the client ended? with a straight socket server it appears to me that whenever I've received everything from a single send(), recv() returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can't *ever* (reliably) differentiate sends from the client using the socket system calls alone. TCP is designed to reliably deliver a "stream" of bytes from peer1 to peer2, not "messages". There are tons of factors - and various race conditions - that can affect how many bytes get delivered with a given `recv` call.

Consider for example, if some packets get dropped by a router along the way while you're sending message 1, but by then you've sent message 2. TCP is designed to retry when packets get dropped. But now, the operating system may choose to just concatenate your two "messages" and send them in one hunk. A `recv` on the server might then deliver both messages into your buffer. Or depending on buffer sizes and timing, you could get the end of message1 and the beginning of message2.

If you need distinct messages, you need to put your own "framing" around them. There are a number of schemes for doing that but one simple way is to prepend each message with a fixed-length field indicating how long the remainder of the message is:

```
[4-byte binary length field indicating length of message 1]
message 1 blah blah
[4-byte binary length of message 2]
message 2 blah blah
...
```

The other side then first receives the fixed-length "header" (calling `recv` multiple times if necessary to get all 4 bytes), then receives the number of "payload" bytes indicated (again calling `recv` as many times as necessary).

All that being said, your `read` function *can* have a loop that calls `recv` over and over again, you just need to handle the `BlockingIOError` exception. That exception is telling you that there is no more data to receive *right now*. It doesn't indicate an unrecoverable error. So you can structure your code something like this:

```
while True:
    select() # Wait for socket to become readable
    callback to read()

def read():
    while True:
        try:
            data = recv()
        except BlockingIOError:
            # End of data for now, return to select
            break
          
        if data:
            append-to-buffer()
        else:
            # EOF (peer closed connection)
            break
```